# How to check in view if my environment is production?

Tags: php, phalcon

How to check in view if my environment is production? I am new to Phalcon so sorry if my question is dumb.

Comment: See here might help https://forum.phalcon.io/discussion/16823/view-not-rendering-in-production-environment

Comment: https://forum.phalcon.io/discussion/13793/create-development-environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) to set and manage your environment parameters in phalcon.